# iOS Network Packet Analyzer app

Tags: ios

I need to start developing an iOS application which will need to capture and analyze network traffic by connecting to certain devices. It will be replacing a java based desktop application which does the same thing using JPCAP: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/index.html

From what I can find out, JPCAP uses a C/C++ library to get the job done. The problem I am running into is not knowing how I can use JPCap in my iOS applications since it is java based even though it is based on C/C++ which Objective-C is a superset of.

If anyone can give me any ideas on how I can get this done or if there are any other API's 
native to Objective-C, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use the existing C/C++ library?

Comment: You can use pcap itself: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/pcap_next.3.html

Comment: Off-topic, but still: there is no "C/C++", those are two distinct and very, very different languages. Also, Objective-C is no superset of C++, just as C++ is no superset of C.

Comment: @Maz - based on initial conversations, JPCap contains "powerful and complex algorithms" even though I don't know yet what those are.
@ abalogh - thanks for the link, this definitely gives me a great starting point and hope.
@Jim - the text "C/C++" was not meant to equate the two languages in any way. Objective-C is not a superset of C++ ,but it is a superset of C. I am fully aware that adding "++" to the end of a language's name doesn't automatically mean it is a superset of that language.

Comment: You can use Objective-C++ by changing the extension of an objective-c file to .mm instead of .m

Comment: You probably need a jailbroken device for this, because root user privileges are required for package capturing